# If 2 Equations with different variables are equal, then they are constant?

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\phi:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $\psi:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be $C^{\infty}$ maps, and $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^3$ by $$f(u,v):(u,v,\phi(u)+\psi(v))$$ and set $M:=f(\mathbb R^2)$
>
> Let $H$ be the mean curvature of $M$, show that if $H=0$  then $\exists\lambda\in\mathbb R$, s.t.
>
> $\phi''(u)=\lambda(1+\phi'(u)^2)$$\qquad$ and $\qquad$$\psi''(v)=\lambda(1+\psi'(v)^2)$

I did the computation finally i got

$(1+\phi'(u)^2)\psi''(v)=-(1+\psi'(v)^2)\phi''(u)$, which is equivalent to

$\frac{-\psi''(v)}{(1+\psi'(v)^2)}=\frac{\phi''(u)}{(1+\phi'(u)^2)}$, So LHS depends from v and RHS from u, can we conclude from that the fractions must be constant ?

Comment: Yep that's exactly right. This is a common technique in PDE. If $\frac{\phi''(u)}{(1+\phi'(u))^2}$ were a nonconstant function of $u$, this dependence would appear on the left side and vice versa.